# Taking data from a javascript object and using react to pass data using props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My goal is to take data from a javascript file, and then pass that data to another component in my project using react.

I am unsure of what I am doing incorrectly.

I am receiving no errors (in vscode), it is just not showing up on the screen.

In the console I am receiving these errors
[Console Errors]
[image: 1]

here is also an image of my file structure [File Structure]
[image: 2]

here is the javascript object (in its own file).

```
export default data = [
{
    id:1,
    url:"../public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png",
    description:"HipHopCard",
    title:"Hip Hop",
},
{
    id:2,
    url:"../public/MainCardImages/houseMainCard.png",
    description:"House Card",
    title:"House",
    }
]
```

Here is the main component (app)

```
import Data from "./data"
import MainCard from './components/MainCard'
function App() {
  const mainCards = Data.map(card => {
    return(
      <MainCard 
          image={card.url}
          key={card.id}
          title={card.title}
      />

    )
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mainCards}
   </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

And here is the component where I intend to pass the props to (MainCard)

```
function MainCard(props){
    return(
        <div className="mainCard">
            <img src={props.image} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainCard
```

Comment: Can you expand on what errors you are getting, or is it simply not showing up as you want it to?

Comment: Hi @Mathias thanks for your comment, I have amended my post to be more concise. I hope that helps.

Comment: In the Developer tools of the browser, can you confirm that it is building the DOM correctly. It could be that the URL for the images are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`. `process` is a global variable if you are in a Node environment. However, your error log indicates that you are not compiling the data file. Therefore it does not exist in the browser environment when it gets executed.

Two approaches to solve this:

1. If you remove `process.env.PUBBLIC_URL` and supply the full path to the image in the string you can avoid that. (Example: `url: "images/MainCardImages.hiphopMainCard.png",`)
2. If you have a compiler, such as webpack, that can replace environment variables then this should work as well.

**Edit:**

I can see that you are using vite, which is a build tool and functions as a local server. I assume it serves all files inside of the `public` folder under the same URL. That would make it something like `http://localhost:5432/public/yourfilehere.ext`.

This means that you have to provide the path inside the image tag `<img src="<path>" />` relative to the URL.

The path to an image is not resolved at compile time but rather in the browser. So `../` no longer represents your file structure. It represents a new request. If you start an image path with `/` then it will start at the top level of the url. Say you have an img-tag under the url *mysite.com/foo/bar/site* and your image path is `/image.png` then the browser will look for it at `mysite.com/image.png`. However if you omit the first `/` then it will take it relative to the url which would mean `mysite.com/foo/bar/site/image.png`

To loop back I think your object would have to look like this:

```js
export default [
    {
        id:1,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png",
        description:"HipHopCard",
        title:"Hip Hop",
    },
    {
        id:2,
        url:"/public/MainCardImages/houseMainCard.png",
        description:"House Card",
        title:"House",
    }
];
```

Comment: based on your answer, I have amended the full path to the images. Yet the problem persists. I will also edit my question to reflect the changes you suggested.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the screenshot. I'm not super familiar with Vite. But the path of the images you provide have to be the paths when served through the browser. So for instance `/public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png`. The first `/` means the path starts at the root of the url. So after the `localhost:1234` part. (I assume you are accessing it on localhost and some port)

I'll expand my answer to add some more context on image paths.

Comment: Hi and thanks for both your comment back and answer to my question.
unfortunately the problem is persisting. Based on the error from the console (data.js?t=1660010574064:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at data.js?t=1660010574064:1:21)
This is telling me that the problem does reside within my data.js file
I am just not sure what is preventing from data being referenced correctly.

Comment: @c0nsy Oh I'm just now seeing it. You have a syntax error as well. You have to remove the word `data` after `export default [ ... ]` or other wise say something like: `const data = [...]; export default data;`